# Getting an error that I cannot use an object because it is on the wrong thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls, dispatcher

I have a problem with an event that comes from other thread, I can't invoke my function in first Thread.

This is the code:

```
namespace Gestion_Photo_CM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        GestionRecherche gRech = new GestionRecherche();
        Dispatcher disp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gRech.evt_creer_objimage += afficherimage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Affichage dynamique des images
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path"></param>
        public void afficherimage(Image obj)
        {
            if (disp.CheckAccess())
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate () { afficherimage(obj); });
            }
            else
            {
                this.RootGrid.Children.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validation du chemin entré
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btn_valid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string cheminDossier = tbfolderpath.Text;
            Thread thScanDossier = new Thread(delegate () { gRech.ScanDossiers(cheminDossier); });
            thScanDossier.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thScanDossier.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

When the programme comes to this line:

```
this.RootGrid.Children.Add(obj);
```

An Exception says that it can't use the object because it is on another Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your condition back to front. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Dispatcher.CheckAccess`, it returns:

> **true** if the calling thread is the thread associated with this Dispatcher; otherwise, **false**.

You need to call `Invoke` in the case it returns `false`:

```
if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    this.RootGrid.Children.Add(obj);
}
else
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate () { afficherimage(obj); });
}
```

I'd also strongly suggest looking at `Task.Run` instead of working directly with `Thread`.

Comment: Thank's for your answer guy. I've just miss ! character in this line but it make the same thing when I test it.

Comment: @C.MARTIN in which case, the issue is you are creating the `Image` on a background thread.